# Remove postDelayed in android

Tags: android, textview

I am using `postDelayed` with `TextView` to hide it after some time. Now, I want to remove `postDelayed` if user click on button.
**My code is as below :**

```
tvRQPoint.setText("+100");
tvRQPoint.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tvRQPoint.setText("");
    }
}, 10000);
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your thread in separate place below...

```
private Runnable mTimerExecutor = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        tvRQPoint.setText("");
    }
};
```

Then call it as follows to execute....

```
tvRQPoint.postDelayed(mTimerExecutor, 10000);
```

When you want to cancel the `postDelay` execution then cancel as follows...

```
tvRQPoint.removeCallbacks(mTimerExecutor);
```

Comment: mTimerHandler stands for ?

Comment: sorry, it was from my code...now, I have updated my code...see it.

Comment: Since your problem solved then you should close this question by accepting an answer or if you solved the problem by yourself then post it and accept it.

Comment: I clicked on right to mark your post as answer but It said to tried after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

check this

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    tvRQPoint.setText("");
  }
 };  

tvRQPoint.setText("+100");
tvRQPoint.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
```

to remove it

```
    tvRQPoint.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code inside onClick. It will remove.

```
private final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            tvRQPoint.setText("");
            Handler handler = new Handler(); 
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    }
};
```

and then use this inside onClick of button

```
handler.removeCallbacks(r);
```

For more information check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: tvRQPoint is TextView. What is myHandler stands for ?

Comment: You have used `new Runnable()` means somewhere you are creating an object of runnable. Then you have to use that object and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean clicked=false;
```

onClick event

```
clicked=true;
```

and in postDelayed

```
tvRQPoint.setText("+100");
tvRQPoint.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if(!clicked)
           tvRQPoint.setText("");
    }
}, 10000);
```